# PL/SQL - NOCOPY parameter to boost performance

Tags: database, oracle, performance, plsql

I was wondering about how passing `NOCOPY` as a function parameter can increase performance in a function returning a `SYS_REFCURSOR`.

After reading the Oracle documentation, I read the following:

> This technique can give significant speedup if you are passing back large amounts of data in OUT parameters, such as collections, big VARCHAR2 values, or LOBs.

Since `SYS_REFCURSORS` are pointers to a result set for a query and `SELECT` is the fastest operation in SQL, is there any advantage of passing such thing as `<SYS_REFCURSOR> OUT NOCOPY SYS_REFCURSOR` in a function?

I found [this thread](https://www.dba-village.com/village/dvp_forum.OpenThread?ThreadIdA=69781&DestinationA=RSS) but two opinions emerge:

1 - We can increase the performance calling by reference, not by value as follows:

```
Procedure (vRefCur OUT NOCOPY SYS_REFCURSOR).
```

2 - `SYS_REFCURSOR` is already a pointer [(link)](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2366696?tstart=0) and to boost performance one should optimise the SQL statement.

What do you think?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for performance - there is no big difference.

When `NOCOPY` is not specified Oracle will just create **another copy** of a pointer.
So if you do not want to have two same pointers in the system - provide the NOCOPY hint.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 4):

For `SYS_REFCURSOR` is does not make any difference. `SYS_REFCURSOR` is just a pointer, i.e. the size is only a couple of bytes.

You would get a difference for `LOB` which might have a size of several Giga- or even Tera Bytes.

Comment: Yes, I get that! Thank you :)